# How to export all LibreOffice Writer pages in one go as images?

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, export

I've generated a serial letter with 300 pages. Each page is different and each page contains emojis. Due a bug in LibreOffice, emojis won't be displayed in the exported pdf: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=129523

LibreOffice Writer offers to export single pages as images. The emojis are rendered in this case. My question is, how can I export all 300 pages in one go to 300 images?

I'm using the following version of LibreOffice:

```
Version: 7.4.0.3 / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 40(Build:3)
CPU threads: 8; OS: Linux 5.19; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); UI: en-US
7.4.0-3
Calc: threaded
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest macro that will perform this task looks like this:

```
Sub StoreEachPageToPNG()
Dim oDoc As Variant, oViewCursor As Variant
Dim iPageCount As Long, iPage As Long 
Dim sOriginalURL As String, sFileURL As String 
Dim Args(1) as New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    Args(0).Name = "FilterName"
    Args(0).Value = "writer_png_Export"

    oDoc = ThisComponent
    iPageCount = oDoc.getCurrentController().PageCount
    oViewCursor = oDoc.getCurrentController().getViewCursor()
    sOriginalURL = oDoc.getURL()
    oViewCursor.jumpToFirstPage()
    For iPage = 1 To iPageCount
        sFileURL = Replace(sOriginalURL, ".odt", " - " & Format(iPage, "000") & ".png")
        oDoc.StoreToURL(sFileURL, Args)
        If Not oViewCursor.jumpToNextPage() Then End
    Next iPage
End Sub
```

If you need to change, for example, the resolution, you will have to add a few lines of code

Comment: Thank you very much! This works, but I struggle to change the resolution. How can I change the resolution? I've recorded a macro and applied `Args(1).Name = "FilterData"` and its value, but it always exports in the default size. Any ideas?

Comment: May be so - [**How to set image quality for writer_png_Export using libreoffice's storeToURL**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48260590/14094617)? Change the square brackets to parentheses and remove the semicolons at the end of the line - so the Java code becomes the Basic code

Comment: I've tried this too, unfortunately no success. I've created a follow up question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1741443/how-to-set-the-resolution-of-a-macro-exporting-images-of-a-libreoffice-writer-pa

Answer (score 0):

From https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/use-soffice-to-convert-from-doc-to-png-images/41621/3:

> Only [the] first page is exported to raster image formats.

The solution given in that answer is to export as PDF and then convert from PDF to an image format. However, it sounds like that won't work in your case.

It's not too hard to write a macro to export a draw page; however if it's a letter then you probably want the text on the page, not only the images.

You could write a macro that goes to each page and then calls export like in the menu. There is an example of using `oViewCursor.jumpToPage()` at https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/basic-macro-to-export-specific-pages-of-a-writer-document/30553. It looks something like this:

```
oViewCursor = oDoc.CurrentController.getViewCursor()
oViewCursor.jumpToLastPage()
iPageCount = oViewCursor.getPage()
For iPage = 1 To iPageCount
    oViewCursor.jumpToPage(iPage)
Next
```

Get dispatcher code by turning on macro recording and going to *File > Export*. Then call that recorded code inside the `For` loop.

The disadvantage with this is that using an `uno:ExportTo` dispatcher call for image formats requires you to press OK for each page. You could use 3rd party software such as AutoHotkey to press the OK button automatically. Or perhaps it would work well enough to hold down or repeatedly press enter.

Here is example dispatcher code.

```
document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

dim args1(3) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args1(0).Name = "URL"
args1(0).Value = "file:///path/to/your/folder/filename.png"
args1(1).Name = "FilterName"
args1(1).Value = "writer_png_Export"
args1(2).Name = "FilterData"
args1(2).Value = Array( _
    Array("Compression",0,6,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE), _
    Array("Interlaced",0,1,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE), _
    Array("Translucent",0,1,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE), _
    Array("PixelWidth",0,816,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE), _
    Array("PixelHeight",0,1056,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE), _
    Array("LogicalWidth",0,21587,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE), _
    Array("LogicalHeight",0,27936,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE))
args1(3).Name = "SelectionOnly"
args1(3).Value = false

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:ExportTo", "", 0, args1())
```

**EDIT**:

@JohnSUN's answer using `StoreToURL` does not require pressing OK, so that is better than using a dispatcher call. However, you may still find some of the arguments shown above helpful.

Comment: Just a little clarification: the phrase "Only [the] first page is exported" has misled many people. Actually "Only one CURRENT page is exported". The fact is that most often the conversion from the command line was discussed, and in this case, immediately after loading the document, the current page is the first one. If this were the case, then our code that move the `ViewCursor` from page to page would not give a result.

Comment: Makes sense. I was confused when I read Mike's answer, so thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't get this idea going. I have problems to set the the different file names. Even though I overwrite the same file again and again, the macro crashes.