# How to set the resolution of a macro exporting images of LibreOffice Writer pages?

Tags: macros, libreoffice, openoffice

Previously I've asked how to export all pages of a LibreOffice Writer document to images. I've got [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1741308/how-to-export-all-libreoffice-writer-pages-in-one-go-as-images/1741331#1741331) answer.

I've adapted the macro towards my needs and this is my current code:

```
Sub StoreEachPageToWebP()
    Dim oDoc As Variant, oViewCursor As Variant
    Dim iPageCount As Long, iPage As Long 
    Dim sOriginalURL As String, sFileURL As String 
    dim args1(1) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    args1(0).Name = "FilterName"
    args1(0).Value = "writer_webp_Export"
    args1(1).Name = "FilterData"
    args1(1).Value = Array(Array("Quality",0,75,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("Lossless",0,true,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("PixelWidth",0,1000,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("PixelHeight",0,647,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("LogicalWidth",0,26455,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("LogicalHeight",0,17116,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE))

    oDoc = ThisComponent        
    iPageCount = oDoc.getCurrentController().PageCount
    oViewCursor = oDoc.getCurrentController().getViewCursor()
    sOriginalURL = oDoc.getURL()
    oViewCursor.jumpToFirstPage()
    For iPage = 1 To iPageCount
        sFileURL = Replace(sOriginalURL, ".odt", "-" & Format(iPage, "000") & ".webp")
        oDoc.StoreToURL(sFileURL, args1)
        If Not oViewCursor.jumpToNextPage() Then End
    Next iPage
End Sub
```

Unfortunately `FilterData` options seem to be ignored. The exported WebP-Images always have the same resolution, which is the standard size of the page. When I export it manually it works. I've used the macro recorded to get the options for `FilterData` so I can be quite sure that they are correct. The recorded macro looks like this:

```
sub RecordedPageExportAsWebP
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem define variables
dim document   as object
dim dispatcher as object
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem get access to the document
document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args1(3) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args1(0).Name = "URL"
args1(0).Value = "file:///home/user/Documents/namecards-all.webp"
args1(1).Name = "FilterName"
args1(1).Value = "writer_webp_Export"
args1(2).Name = "FilterData"
args1(2).Value = Array(Array("Quality",0,75,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("Lossless",0,true,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("PixelWidth",0,1000,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("PixelHeight",0,647,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("LogicalWidth",0,26455,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("LogicalHeight",0,17116,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE))
args1(3).Name = "SelectionOnly"
args1(3).Value = false

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:ExportTo", "", 0, args1())


end sub
```

What am I missing here?

I'm using the following version of LibreOffice:

```
Version: 7.4.0.3 / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 40(Build:3)
CPU threads: 8; OS: Linux 5.19; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); UI: en-US
7.4.0-3
Calc: threaded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, a few extra lines of code will be required to set the resolution:

```
Sub StoreEachPageToPNG()
Dim oDoc As Variant, oViewCursor As Variant
Dim iPageCount As Long, iPage As Long 
Dim sOriginalURL As String, sFileURL As String 
Dim pngFilterData(1) As New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    pngFilterData(0).Name = "PixelWidth"
    pngFilterData(0).Value = 1634 ' or as much as you need
    pngFilterData(1).Name = "PixelHeight"
    pngFilterData(1).Value = 2114 ' take care to maintain proportions
Dim Args(1) As New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    Args(0).Name = "FilterName"
    Args(0).Value = "writer_png_Export"
    Args(1).Name = "FilterData"
    Args(1).Value = pngFilterData
    
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    iPageCount = oDoc.getCurrentController().PageCount
    oViewCursor = oDoc.getCurrentController().getViewCursor()
    sOriginalURL = oDoc.getURL()
    oViewCursor.jumpToFirstPage()
    For iPage = 1 To iPageCount
        sFileURL = Replace(sOriginalURL, ".odt", " - " & Format(iPage, "000") & ".png")
        oDoc.StoreToURL(sFileURL, Args)
        If Not oViewCursor.jumpToNextPage() Then End
    Next iPage
End Sub
```

Be careful when increasing the values for PixelWidth and PixelHeight, don't be greedy - the size of the output file grows rapidly!

*Of course, this code is still far from perfect - for example, this macro does not check if the current document has a name (if the file is saved), if there is permission to write files to the target folder, if files with the target name already exist and are not locked, etc.*

Comment: Thank you so much! It works.